# How to show same id data in single row in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
public function get_orderProduct($loginuserID) {
    $this->db->select('client_order.*,product.image_gallery,product.name');
    $this->db->from('client_order');
    $this->db->join('product','client_order.productID = product.productID','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('client_order.clientID',$loginuserID);
    $this->db->where('client_order.status',1);
    $this->db->order_by('client_order.id','desc');
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    $result = $sql->result();
    return $result;
}

<?php 
  if(count($result) > 0){
              $i=1;
              foreach($result as $row){
                    $img = explode(",", $row->image_gallery);
  ?>
                    <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row->orderID; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                    </tr>
  <?php
              $i++;
              }    
        }else{
  ?>
              <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    No order available!
              </div>
  <?php
        }
  ?>
```

I have two product with same orderID and I want to show same orderID product in single row. Now, Here it show in different different row. So, How can I show in single row? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Hi! Did you dump your query result, to see its output? I'm not really good at SQL, but maybe your request would need some `group_by` so that your `SELECT (...) product.name` results will be contactenated somehow for a given order.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you have to create an empty array to store orderids.Before you print the orderid you have to search the array using `in_array` method, if orderid exists ignore printing it, otherwise print and push the orderID to the array using `array_push` method.

```
<?php
$ids = array();
$i=1;
foreach($result as $row){
      $img = explode(",", $row->image_gallery);
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td>
<?php 
  if(!in_array($row->orderID,$ids))
  {
     echo $row->orderID;
     array_push($ids,$row->orderID); 
  }
?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}  
?>
```